# How to Plot Columns of x and y Coordinates with the Third Column as Legend

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Assuming i have a data frame with three columns: x : x coordinates - y : y coordinates - type : detrermining the type (there are only two)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {"x" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
        "y" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
        "type" : ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to plot the dots using columns x and y:

```
plt.scatter(df["x"], df["y"])
plt.show()
```

However, i want the points to have different color based on the value of type column, such that:

points (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3) to have the same color (they belong to class one) and points (4, 4) and (5, 5) to have a same color (they belong to class two).

I tried

```
plt.scatter(df["x"], df["y"])
plt.legend(df["type"])
plt.show()
```

and

```
df.plot.scatter(x = "x", y = "y", legend = "type")
```

but neither works. I appreciate your help and input.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pure matplotlib is more difficult.
But you can use seaborn (which is a basically high-level interface version of matplotlib) to do that easily:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="x", y="y", hue="type")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `c` parameter in `df.scatter`:

```
df.plot.scatter(x = 'x', y = 'y', c = df['type'].map({'one':'b', 'two': 'g'}))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I never fully understood how to use this parameter. Thanks

Comment: It takes a list of colors equal to the number of data points.    Here I am just mapping you values to two colors.